# quopri lib strips characters like this '='

Tags: python

Why quopri.decodestring('fasfsdfasdf=') strips '='
so output is '**fasfsdfasdf**'
if I have base64 encoded picture I cannot decode because of padding error one or two '=' missing

Comment: That is part of the specification that `quopri` implements. I am not sure, though, why do you want to mix `quopri` and `base64`.

Comment: It's legacy code and there is part where mail is being processed and if message encoded in one of specific charset then m = quopri.decodestring(message) before decoding. Any way thanks for answer.

Comment: You may be running into [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Perhaps you should try describing the full picture, including where the problem occurs and what your restrictions are.